# How to generate .xsd from a .cs using xsd.exe tool?

Tags: xsd, xsd.exe

I have a .cs file that contains a subclass of XTypedElement and IXMetaData. Microsoft has a [tool that generates XSD files automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from managed code, but it doesn't accept .cs files. It only accepts .exe, .dll, .xdr, .xml, and .xsd.

How do I convert my .cs file into a .xsd file with this tool?

Comment: tried.But not able to find any suitable answer

Comment: first hit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @MitchWheat: It may be the first hit, but it doesn't describe how to convert a .cs file to an .xsd file.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to compile it into dll or exe file, i.e. .NET assembly, and then use this as an input for xsd.exe

If you want to convert only a specific class, use the following command:

```
xsd bin\Release\MyAssembly.exe /type:The.FullName.Of.YourType
```