# How to generate xsd from C# class file using visual studio command prompt?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xsd, xsd.exe

I'm using the following command, but it's not working:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin>xsd /c /l:cs
>   SubsystemReg.cs

Lets say this is my Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PaymentControllerGUI
{
    public class EmptyClass
    {
    }
}
```

and I'm trying this.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin>xsd /c /l:cs EmptyClass.cs

Error:

> invalid command line argument: 'SubsystemReg.cs'

Comment: it gives error
Error: invalid command line argument: 'SubsystemReg.cs'.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598531/how-to-generate-xsd-from-a-cs-using-xsd-exe-tool ?

Answer (score 8):

Using the `XSD.exe`, you should pass the `DLL` file path which your class is compiled in, ***instead*** of the CS class code file itself as you pass now.

For instance, if your class is compiled in `SubsystemReg.dll`, call XSD.exe like that:

```
XSD.exe C:\SubsystemReg.dll
```

Here is an example from MSDN:

> The following command generates XML schemas for all types in the
>   assembly myAssembly.dll and saves them as schema0.xsd in the current
>   directory.

```
xsd myAssembly.dll
```

**UPDATE:**

You can generate XSD from DLL for a specific type by specifying the fully-qualified path of the Type, for example:

```
xsd.exe YourAssembly.dll /type:YourNamespace.YourType
```

**Per your case, just do:**

```
xsd.exe PaymentControllerGUI.dll /type:PaymentControllerGUI.EmptyClass
```

Comment: I don't have dll file. This file is part of my project. I just copied it to this location and trying.

Comment: No problem, you can specify the required type to be generate as XSD. See my update.

Comment: I didn't understand your solution. As I'm saying I don't have dll file.

Comment: So you **must** have one in order to achieve what you want. Otherwise, no way to do it with `XSD.EXE`.

Comment: I assume that you are working with Visual Studio, so just compile your project, take the DLL from the BIN folder and use it as I suggest in my answer.

Comment: Tried already, not working
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin>xsd PaymentControllerGUI.dll /type:PaymentControllerGUI.SubsystemReg.cs
PaymentControllerGUI is namespace and type is SubsystemReg.cs. is this correct ??

Comment: No, don't do it like that. This is the convention: `xsd.exe YourAssembly.dll /type:YourNamespace.YourType`

Comment: what should I write in place of YouNamespace.YourType?

Comment: Dude, are you doing time pass? If you dont know please dont waste time.
I have already tried this. getting error.
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
 Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\PaymentControllerGUI.dll' or one of its dependencies. Th
is assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and ca
nnot be loaded.

Comment: You are trying to open your dll from the VS folder!!

Comment: I have copied cs file and dll file to different location. then trying

Comment: You don't need .cs files

Comment: I don't know how you are doing but I'm not able to generate it. :(

Comment: @YairNevet I salute your patience.

Comment: @YairNevet, just found this years later.  I'm trying to do what you're saying.  Using command prompt, cd to Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\, then enter this:  xsd.exe "C:\MyProjects\Dev\Source\eFI\SCC.WebAPI\bin\SCC.WebAPI.dll" /type:SCC.WebAPI.Models.transactions    Getting an error the dll is not of correct type: Could not load file or assembly, An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  CAN I USE MY dll for the visual studio project where my class is defined?  Or do I need a separate project with just the classes?  Thanks

Comment: Oh, I just figured it out.  There's a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of the xsd.exe.  Had to change directory to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\x64 and it worked!!!!  My Visual Studio Project's dll is 6-bit

Comment: @DebbieA great, I'm glad to hear. Please upvote if it helps as you described.